# Shell scripting: find specific subdirectories, cd into them and execute commands

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I want to create a script that finds all instances of Markdown files in subdirectories, goes into these with `cd`, and executes some command on them. Right now I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `find . -name "*.md" -type f`; do
    cd `dirname $file` && pandoc -s -o "${file%.md}.tex" "$file"
    cd `dirname $file` && pandoc -s -o "${file%.md}.pdf" "$file"
done
```

where `pandoc -s -o example.md example.pdf` generates a PDF from a Markdown file with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).

Note that I need to `cd` into these directories because I have relative paths in my Markdown documents which pandoc only detects correctly if executed in this specific directory.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and this error is thrown:
`pandoc: ./example_directory/example_file.md: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

Edit: I am a beginner in shell scripting, please consider that :)

Comment: Are there multiple different files in each directory, and you only want to work on those with the directory name minus the ".md" part? Seems like a simpler find command is a possibility, examples of directories & their contents might help. And [pandoc's `--dump-args` option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) looks useful for debugging.

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes, in general there are multiple files in each directory, and I want this script to operate on every file. Example: A directory `foo` may contain a `foo.md` **and** a `bar.md`. Thanks for the debugging tip as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `find` returns relative paths like `./example_directory/example_file.md` because you told it to start in `.` which is relative. After you `cd` to the proper directory this path is no longer valid. You need `basename` or `"${file##*/}"` to strip the leading part of it.

But there are other problems:

- Your script never does `cd` back; the next `cd` would try to change the directory according to a relative path, starting from a wrong place – and it will fail.
- `` for file in `find . -name "*.md" -type f`; do `` is wrong. It's the first one of [Bash Pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

The right way is to use `find -execdir` or `find -exec`. Only the latter is required by POSIX. Since it's good to start a shell anyway (to benefit from syntax like `${file%.md}.tex`), we can use `find -exec` for portability and then `cd` from within the invoked shell:

```
find . -name "*.md" -type f -exec sh -c '
   cd "${1%/*}" || exit 1
   file="${1##*/}"
   pandoc -s -o "${file%.md}.tex" -- "$file"
   pandoc -s -o "${file%.md}.pdf" -- "$file"
' sh {} \;
```

Notes:

- Most of this code is a single-quoted shell script "embedded" into `-exec` clause.
- There's no need to `cd` back because each shell (one for each matching object) will start and change its directory independently.
- I assumed `pandoc` supports `--` as the end of options marker. The marker is crucial in case `"$file"` expands to a string starting with `-`. Such string would otherwise be interpreted as an option, not operand.
- If we used `-exec sh -c '…' sh {} +`, a single `sh` would get paths to multiple `.md` files in general. This should perform better than our current solution which spawns a separate shell for each matching file. But then the inner script would have to be more complicated in order to serve multiple files. I decided to KISS (keep it simple and stupid).

Comment: Thank you very much! Also great explanations, which help me understand your solution better.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the jobs running in parallel:

```
find . -name "*.md" -type f |
  parallel 'cd {//} && ( pandoc -s -o {/.}.tex {/}; pandoc -s -o {/.}.pdf {/} )'
```